# returning a row value from a column based on the values in other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I couldn't think of a good want to say thing concisely in the search (or the title), so I didn't find an answer, but what I am after is: I have a table with many columns, the first two columns are the name and the current version number. Each subsequent column corresponds to a version number, i.e. column 3 is version 1, column 4 is version 2 and so on.

What I want do is use only the name value get back the value in the version column indicated in the current version column. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "B", "C"),
             Current_Version = c(2, 3, 1),
             "1" = c(10, 20, 30),
             "2" = c(15, 25, 35),
             "3" = c(20, 30, 40))
```

So if I chose "B" in this example I would get back "30". I feel like there is a and easy way in base r or dplyr to get to that the right value here that I am missing.

I know I could do something like `df$3[df$Name=="B"]` to get what I want, but the `$3` that indicates the version number will be changing dynamically in the file as people make edits, hence the Current_Version column to note what version column to use. I don't want to be changing the code every time someone edits the file.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
j1 <- with(df, match(Current_Version, sub("^X", "", names(df))))
i1 <- df$Name == "B"
df[i1, j1[i1]]
[1] 30
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do it also this way:

```
row <- df[df$Name == "B", ]
row[, row$Current_Version + 2]

[1] 30
```